# Writing Apache Arrow columnar data to GCP BigQuery [Java]

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-arrow

I am working on a PoC which aims at ingesting GCP BigQuery with table data in Apache Arrow columnar format.

So far I have found that BigQuery supports Reading table data in Arrow format but not able to find any concrete way to Write data in Arrow format.

I have explored the BigQuery Client and Storage APIs.

FYI for the ingestion I'm reading data from PubSub with a Data flow Pipeline and converting the data to Arrow columnar format.

The following examples show how we can read from bigwuery using arrow format.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquerystorage-arrow-quickstart

https://egkatzioura.com/2021/06/08/bigquery-storage-api-arrow/

I wanted to know if the same can be applicable for Write to BigQuery